# Embed youtube "Shorts" videos

Tags: video, youtube, embed

I have this code and it works just fine.

```
if( strcasecmp( 'www.youtube.com/watch', $link[2] ) == 0 && $this->params( $params, $link[3], 'v' ) )
      return '<iframe width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"  src="'.$link[1].'www.youtube.com/embed/'.$params['v'].'?rel=0&amp;playsinline=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    else if( preg_match( '/^(?:www\.)?youtu\.be\/([^\/]+)/i', $link[2], $matches ))
      return '<iframe width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"  src="'.$link[1].'www.youtube.com/embed/'.$matches[1].'?rel=0&amp;playsinline=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

And it works just fine, with auto replace links with video. But now, youtube have this thing where short videos have a link with "Shorts"

Example: https://youtube.com/shorts/d1wXX9xO_2o?feature=share

That will not embed automatically. Any idea how to fix this?

I have tried:

```
else if( preg_match( '/^(?:www\.)?youtube\.com/shorts\/([^\/]+)/i', $link[2], $matches ))
          return '<iframe width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"  src="'.$link[1].'www.youtube.com/embed/'.$matches[1].'?rel=0&amp;playsinline=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

But no luck.

Comment: You have to change/update your regex for extract its video_id.

Comment: But it does grab the video ID, which is d1wXX9xO_2o. The upper code does work with extracting a video from youtube just fine. I just cant seem to add "shorts" in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
else if( preg_match( '/youtube\.com\/shorts\/(\w+\s*\/?)*([0-9]+)*$/i', $link[2], $matches ) )
        return '<iframe width="'.$width.'" height="'.$height.'"  src="'.$link[1].'www.youtube.com/embed/'.$matches[1].'?rel=0&amp;playsinline=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. Just for others,  I had to change preg match "#^http(s?)\://www\.youtube\.com/shorts/(.*)#i".

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use different code for shorts just use the identifier from the end of their url and this iframe:

```
<iframe
 width="720"
 height="576"
 src="{{'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $video}}"
 title="YouTube video player"
 frameborder="0"
 allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
 allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

tested and it work perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this solution by Document360, and it worked.

Link to solution:

[**How to embed YouTube Shorts?**](https://docs.document360.com/docs/embed-youtube-shorts)

Copying the video link from the address bar, click on Share, and replace "**/shorts/**" with "**/embed/**" in the URL. This will allow you to embed any YouTube Shorts in your page or article.